# How to know when TTetheringManager.AutoConnect finishes every time we call it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have an app that sends some messages via Delphi Tethering Components.
First time when I call `TetheringManager1.AutoConnect()`, it triggers *TTetheringManager.OnEndAutoConnect*. But when I call it the second time, it does not trigger the event, although it discovers and connects to other new devices.

I need to know when it finishes connecting, because I want to know when it is safe to send a message to all the apps.

How should I know when **AutoConnect** finishes every time I call it?

Here is my code that I adapted for you to see.

The event:

```
procedure TFTetheringTest.TetheringManager1EndAutoConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ConnectionFinished := True;
end;
```

The call - I adapted it and compacted it in a single procedure for you to get the idea behind:

```
procedure TFTetheringTest.BtnSendMsgClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ConnectionFinished := False;
  TetheringManager1.AutoConnect();
  repeat
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  until ConnectionFinished;
  ConnectionFinished := False;
  // the sending
  for var I := 0 to TetheringAppProfileSender.ConnectedProfiles.Count - 1 do
  begin
      TetheringAppProfileSender.SendString(TetheringAppProfileSender.ConnectedProfiles.Items[I], 'msg', 'Test');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A `ProcessMessages` loop is never a good idea. Use a timer instead, or a `TThread.ForceQueue()` loop. Or, simply move your sending code into the `OnEndAutoConnect` event. NEVER block the main UI thread like you are doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I'll have that in mind.  Anyway, it is just a testing project. I'm just messing with these components, so in a real project I will try to follow your good advice.

Answer (score 0):

After some trail and error I've found the solution to trigger the ***OnEndAutoConnect*** event. The solution is to unpair all the paired managers before calling **AutoConnect**.

This is the only way I've found to trigger the event every time I call **AutoConnect**.

```
  for var I := TetheringManager1.PairedManagers.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    TetheringManager1.UnPairManager(TetheringManager1.PairedManagers[I]);
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      TetheringManager1.AutoConnect();
    end);
```